# How to store login Information from within setup dialog

Tags: deployment

I have created one Windows desktop application using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010). At the time of creating setup for this, in the user interface I am able to `Add Dialog` with textboxes (for storing username, password, email id, and contact number), but now how do I store them, so that I can use these values so that the user can login to the application using this username and password?

I searched, but didn't get anything as I am doing this the first time, so I don't have an  in-depth idea of it.

Comment: What you tried ( Source Code ) till now ... paste it here... i will help you out !!!

Comment: I have referred this page and created form for taking username, password ,email etc info, but how do i store this `username, password` and  check whether they are properly entered so that they can be used for each time user log in to my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *two options*:

### 1. Files

You can store your *application **Login information*** in a **file** with any structure that you want *like XML or etc*.

*If you want to store data for more than one person, you must create a logic with your desired structure for reading/writing data in the file for every one.*

Then, you can add it in your application setup project for copy in where your application will install and use its values.

### 2. Windows OS Registry

you can store your *application **Login information*** in a **subkey of the Windows OS Registry** with any structure that you want.

*If you want to store data for more than one person in every Windows OS user account, you must create a logic with your desired structure for reading/writing data in the value of a subkey in the Windows OS Registry.*

If you want to have *different information for every Windows OS user account*, it's better you write your data in the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** root of the Windows OS Registry. in the other hand, if you want *same information for all Windows OS user accounts*, it's better you write your data in the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** root of the Windows OS Registry.

It's better you add your application subkey in the **Software** (in the *HKEY_CURRENT_USER* root) or **SOFTWARE** (in the *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE* root) subkey.

- *Remember that you must encrypt all data for prevent access to them by
  malicious persons.*
- *You can encrypt them and then write them as Binary in your file or
  the Binary type value of a subkey in the Windows OS Registry.*